# what is the handle_connection in tornado module ioloop simple tcpserver's connection_ready?

Tags: python, tornado

Tornado ioloop.py give a example usage for a simple TCP server,through this simple can run,but what is handle_connection in function connection_ready(the end line)  or need define by myself?

```
    import errno
    import functools
    import tornado.ioloop
    import socket
    def connection_ready(sock, fd, events):
        while True:
            try:
                connection, address = sock.accept()
            except socket.error as e:
                if e.args[0] not in (errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EAGAIN):
                    raise
                return
            connection.setblocking(0)
            handle_connection(connection, address)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.setblocking(0)
        sock.bind(("", port))
        sock.listen(128)
        io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
        callback = functools.partial(connection_ready, sock)
        io_loop.add_handler(sock.fileno(), callback, io_loop.READ)
        io_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `handle_connection` is a function that you would write for your application.

Also see the [`tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpserver.html) class, which is a little easier to use than building on the `IOLoop` directly.